# Why IntelliJ testing doesn't work with multi-module Spring project, while it works with a single module project?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project where its structure is multi-module then IntelliJ testing with coverage doesn't work, and `maven clean install` also fails in the `install` phase where it runs tests. When the project is a single module project everything works just fine.

The project with single module can be found [here](https://github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EG/tree/all_stuff_in_one_module), multi-module version [here](https://github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EG/tree/modularized).

The error output says the following. Yes, it is a compilation error which I don't understand. Why `mvn clean test` works (stuff needed to be on the path) and why `mvn clean install` doesn't. The debug output in both cases says that all the stuff is added tot he path.

I know my approach to split the app to small pieces (interfaces, implementations, tests, and when it comes then exceptions) might be overengineered. However shovel everything into a single module is just a mess for me.

> [INFO] Building repositories.tests 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
> [13/16] [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar
> ]--------------------------------- [INFO] [INFO] ---
> maven-clean-plugin:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ repositories.tests
> --- [INFO] Deleting /Users/andrascsanyi/DEV/github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EG/repositories.tests/target
> [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources
> (default-resources) @ repositories.tests --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8'
> encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to
> copy filtered properties files. [INFO] skip non existing
> resourceDirectory
> /Users/andrascsanyi/DEV/github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EG/repositories.tests/src/main/resources
> [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory
> /Users/andrascsanyi/DEV/github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EG/repositories.tests/src/main/resources
> [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile
> (default-compile) @ repositories.tests --- [INFO] No sources to
> compile [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources
> (default-testResources) @ repositories.tests --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8'
> encoding to copy filtered resources. [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to
> copy filtered properties files. [INFO] skip non existing
> resourceDirectory
> /Users/andrascsanyi/DEV/github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EG/repositories.tests/src/test/resources
> [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile
> (default-testCompile) @ repositories.tests --- [INFO] Changes detected
>
> - recompiling the module! [INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/andrascsanyi/DEV/github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EG/repositories.tests/target/test-classes
>   [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
>   [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [ERROR] /Users/andrascsanyi/DEV/github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EG/repositories.tests/src/test/java/com/encyclopediagalactica/sourceformats/repositories/sourceformat/SaveTests.java:[5,47]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class SourceFormatServiceApplication
>   location: package com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats [ERROR]
>   /Users/andrascsanyi/DEV/github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EG/repositories.tests/src/test/java/com/encyclopediagalactica/sourceformats/repositories/sourceformat/FindAllTests.java:[16,54]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class SourceFormatServiceApplication
>   location: package com.encyclopediagalactica.sourceformats [ERROR]
>   /Users/andrascsanyi/DEV/github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/EG/repositories.tests/src/test/java/com/encyclopediagalactica/sourceformats/repositories/sourceformat/SaveTests.java:[15,33]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol: class SourceFormatServiceApplication
>   [INFO] 3 errors [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: First reformat the output correctly... Second this is **NOT** a multi module build/project it's a aggregator build. The problem is that some of the modules (if I've seen correctly no module) are not using the correct parent.. they are using `spring-boot-starter-parent` instead... Also where have you separated the tests from the code.. for example repositories and repositories.tests ... they should be within the same module... Furthermore the compilation error occurs because there is a dependency to the application module which is a spring boot app which can not being consumed as a dep.

Comment: I followed [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module) tutorial. According to this I did everything well. If I don't include the `application` in tests then I'll get the error about some configuration error. Basically, the test doesn't find the app configuration. As for the formatting. Sorry, something changed in SO and I could not format the output nicely.